# How to direct MATLAB's mex setup to the Microsoft Windows SDK for C++ compiling? (error in setting location)

Tags: c++, windows, matlab, compilation, mex

I am on `Windows Vista`, and want to use `MATLAB` to compile `C++` functions. I had only the `lcc compiler` on the system, as can be seen when running `mex -setup` :

```
mex -setup
Welcome to mex -setup.  This utility will help you set up  
a default compiler.  For a list of supported compilers, see  
http://www.mathworks.com/support/compilers/R2011a/win32.html 
Please choose your compiler for building MEX-files: 
Would you like mex to locate installed compilers [y]/n? y
Select a compiler: 
[1] Lcc-win32 C 2.4.1 in C:\PROGRA~1\MATLAB\R2011a\sys\lcc 
[0] None 
Compiler:
```

since lcc does not work for C++ I installed the **Windows SDK 7.1** from [here(windows site)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=8279). I ran the `Windows SDK 7.1 Command Prompt` to see the directory it is installed to and see `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1`. I then run `mex -setup` again to set the compiler to `Microsoft Visual C++ 2010`, by telling `mex` to not locate the installed compilers, I choose the `Microsoft Visual C++ 2010` option and then the path MATLAB looks at by default is one for `Visual Studio`; `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0`. I try to override it, but there it does not work. Here is the exact actions taken:

```
>> mex -setup
Welcome to mex -setup.  This utility will help you set up  
a default compiler.  For a list of supported compilers, see  
http://www.mathworks.com/support/compilers/R2011a/win32.html 
Please choose your compiler for building MEX-files: 
Would you like mex to locate installed compilers [y]/n? n
Select a compiler: 
[1] Intel C++ 11.1 (with Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 SP1 linker) 
[2] Intel Visual Fortran 11.1 (with Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 SP1 linker) 
[3] Intel Visual Fortran 11.1 (with Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Shell linker) 
[4] Lcc-win32 C 2.4.1 
[5] Microsoft Visual C++ 6.0 
[6] Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 SP1 
[7] Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 SP1 
[8] Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 
[9] Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Express 
[10] Open WATCOM C++ 
[0] None 
Compiler: 8
Warning: The default location for Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 compiler is: 
     "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0" 
     but either that directory does not exist or the configuration 
     is invalid. 
Use C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0 anyway [y]/n? n
Please enter the location of your compiler: [C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0] 
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1
Please verify your choices: 
Compiler: Microsoft Visual C++ 2010  
Location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0 
Are these correct [y]/n?  
***************************************************************************** 
Error: Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 requires the Microsoft Windows Software  
     Development Kit (SDK), but the SDK cannot be found.  Examine your   
     Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 installation. 
*****************************************************************************  
??? Error using ==> mex at 208
Unable to complete successfully.
```

I do not know whether the directory should be different from `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1`, and if there is a way to identify this directory. I also do not know if the way that I give the directory is correct. I tried using single quotes around the directory name and the only variation is the that it stops to ask me whether the directory to visual studio is correct or not, I answer **n** and only this is given.

```
Compiler: Microsoft Visual C++ 2010  
Location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0 
Are these correct [y]/n? n
mex: No compiler selected. No action taken.
```

How can I add the compiler to MATLAB to be able to run mex on C++ funcitons/files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are after the quick and easy approach (and do not use 64-bit matlab) I would suggest you download a free copy of Visual Studio 2010 C++ express and use that. That way mex -setup will detect it.

Comment: Looks like that would do it.

Comment: `Trying to update options file: `C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Roaming\MathWorks\MATLAB\R2011a\mexopts.bat 
From template C:\PROGRA~1\MATLAB\R2011a\bin\win32\mexopts\msvc100freeopts.bat 
Done . . . ` and the compilations proceed without error. Not an elegant solution cause I got this chunky thing on my disk, but none the less it works!